# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS not automounting ZFS pool after reboot

Tags: 16.04, automount, zfs

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my desktop and wanted to move my existing ZFS pool over. I did that by doing the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install zfsutils-linux
$ sudo zfs mount -vO -a
```

The `-vO` switch is for overlay mounting. I mount my ZFS pool over the `/home` directory. If I log out and back in, everything works as expected.

However, when I reboot my machine, the ZFS pool is not automounted, and I have to go through the above steps again. Is there any way to get Ubuntu to automount my ZFS pool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get Ubuntu to automount my ZFS pool by opening up the `/etc/rc.local` file and adding the following line to it:

```
zfs mount -vO -a
```

Now my ZFS pool is automounted on reboot.